# What happens when we create index

Tags: oracle, index

What happens exactly when I create an index on the `empid` column of this `employee` table

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  empid number(5),
  ename varchar2(30),
  sal   number(10,2)
);
```

Let's assume the table contains the below data

```
empid   ename      sal
1       hema       10000
3       suma       10000
2       bheema     15000
4       bhama      20000
5       panama     25000
```

what exactly my doubt is what will be created and stored internally in index..... to improve the performance , whether sorted content of empid or some other information related to rows....?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags, either!

Comment: The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#i5671) explains how indexes work and are stored.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes, their various types and internal structures, are described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#i5671).

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Anatomy of an SQL Index' section at http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy you should found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Indices can be implemented using a variety of data structures. Popular indices include balanced trees, B+ trees and hashes.`

most likely a balanced tree will be created to improve select queries performance
each node in the tree will contain the index columns and a rowid for a quick access to the tables data

Comment: do you meant to say that rowids will be stored in b*tree format

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Let say you do  `CREATE INDEX I01 ON EMPLOYEE ( EMPID )`. 
Your table content will remain unchanged. Creation of index will register its structure visible in views `USER_INDEXES`, `user_tab_columns,` `user_objects`  etc. Also segment is created in default tablespace (for simplification, we will forget case when no data in table and delayed segment creation is set) and visible in `user_segments` and `user_extents`. Inside segment is stored representation of tree structure containing empid values but also rowid. Rowid can be understand as pointer to table line. Tree consists of branch and leaf  nodes. Only leaf nodes contain values, branch nodes serve to find leaf nodes. 
 By default, order is ascending.

Answer (score 0):

I once needed to wrap my head around indexes and understand how they work, and found an article ["Understanding Indexes"](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403) by **rleishman** to be very useful and intuitive. There are also [other nice posts](http://www.orafaq.com/blog/rleishman) by this author.